# Loose coupling with T::AccountId

Tags: loose-coupling

My pallet A:

```
pub trait TraitInPalletA<AccountId> {
    fn do_somthing(
        address: AccountId,
    ) -> DispatchResult;
}

impl<T: Config> TraitInPalletA<T::AccountId> for Pallet<T> {
    fn do_somthing(
        address: T::AccountId,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        // do_something
    }
}
```

My pallet B:

```
use pallet_a::TraitInPalletA;
pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
    // snip
    type TraitA: TraitInPalletA<Self::AccountId>;
}
```

And in runtime:

```
impl pallet_a::Config for Runtime {
    // snip
}

impl pallet_b::Config for Runtime {
    // snip
    type TraitA = Balances;
}
```

When I build my code, it return this error in runtime at 'type TraitA = Balances' line:
type TraitA = Balances;
|                          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `TraitInPalletA<AccountId32>` is not implemented for `pallet_balances::Pallet<Runtime>`

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you set a trait bound for the associated type `TypeA` which requires it to implement trait `TraitInPalletA`. Then you attempt to assign to it a type `Balances` which doesn't implement that trait. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Probably you need to provide an implementation of `TraitInPallet` for `pallet_balances::Pallet` in pallet A.